# Not a useful [default] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I just stumbled upon the [default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/default) tag, and it feels really iffy to me.  You can't be an expert in `default`, it's not a useful thing to filter on, and it's super general.

I'm thinking it should be removed.  Does the community agree?

## Usage guidance

> Refers to an initial, most commonly used option, setting, or value that is automatically assigned to an application or device, outside of user intervention, with the intention of making it usable "out of the box".

## Tag info

> A [default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/default), in computer science, refers to a setting or a value automatically assigned to a software application, computer program or device, outside of user intervention. Such settings are also called presets, especially for electronic devices. Default values are generally intended to make a device (or control) usable *"out of the box"*. A common setting, or at least a usable setting, is typically assigned.
>
> [default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/default) tag should be used for questions regarding
>
> - Default features of programming languages (like default return type of C functions).
> - Default configuration of [protocols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/protocols) and Applications.
>
> **SOURCE**
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_%28computer_science%29)

Comment: There's a required [format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination) to these requests; you will need to take the time to [edit] your post to meet them, as otherwise this post is unlikely to be received well.

Comment: That wiki article should be updated though to use *original* content though; it shouldn't be solely made up of copied content (that isn't even in a quote block, so doesn't meet the referencing guidelines).

Comment: This almost certainly needs _disambiguation_, specifically.  There are at least a few on-topic subjects it covers (e.g., default parameters).

Comment: @ThomA I'll admit to being a bit unclear here.  I wasn't sure if I was requesting tag removal so much as asking whether it should be done.  The usage guidance of [burninate-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request) said it was used "for both requesting a removal, as well as discussing if a tag needs removal".  So I wasn't sure if this should follow the standard burnination request format if it wasn't a formal request to burninate.

Comment: Agreement of the removal can be denoted by the votes on a proper burnination request though; why make a post to ask if we should consider burninating it, to then make a burninating post. It's just an unnecessary step. It's like having a vote to see if we should vote on something.

Comment: But @ThomA, that would eliminate half the meetings I'm forced to attend at work! ;-)

Comment: *"[Default] on a tag"*?

Answer (score -1):

[default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/default) could refer to many things, to which we already have tags for:

- [default-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/default-value)
- [default-parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/default-parameters)/[default-arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/default-arguments)
- [default-constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/default-constructor)

Other meanings that I have not yet seen tags for include:

- The `default` statement of a `switch` statement that is executed if none of the others execute.
- The `default` keyword in languages like C or C++ or Java etc.
- Default configurations as mentioned in the question.

There are already more specific tags for things that [default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/default) could refer to, and others could be created as needed or are arguably not needed (A question about `default` statements in a `switch` could probably just be tagged [switch-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/switch-statement) and the relevant language and that should be good).

Yes, I would say this tag should be burninated, and instances should be replaced with either existing, or new, more specific variants. Or at the very least, this should be made a synonym of a 'default' [default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/default) variation.